# Dependent Annotations In Java 1.6

Tags: java

I want to use multiple annotation on method like

```
  @Transaction
  public void saveUserName(@Conn Connection con, String strName){
   .....
   .....
  }
```

Here, I want to make sure that while using @Conn annotation if @Transaction annotation is not specified on that method then it should show me compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html).  The processor examines all the annotated elements in your program (such as methods and formal parameters, and it can issue warnings just like the compiler does.

Whenever you compile your code, you should run the processor.  You can do this via the `-processor` commnad-line argument to `javac`, for example:

`javac -processor TransactionConnProcessor MyFile.java`

Here is a [tutorial on writing an annotation processor](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html).

Alternately, you could extend an existing analysis tool such as PMD, Jlint, or FindBugs so that it also warns about this error.

Comment: Let's say I want to make sure that if @Transaction annotation is present on method then that method should have instance of Connection otherwise it should show me compile time error in IDE. In short I want to implement Required parameter validation on usage of method level annotation.

Comment: Every IDE has its own mechanism for writing code analyses and reporting problems.  You would need to look at your IDE's documentation.  An annotation processor or plug-in to a static analysis tool is IDE-independent.